# Crop order scheduling in excel

Tags: excel

I am looking for some advice, I have a small micro green business and I have an excel sheet that breaks down the seeds, seed batch amount required, yield etc and so on.

[image]

I want to create a tab where I can input a customer order, I then want excel to schedule that order based on the information contained above in a calendar format on a tab.

I also want excel to calculate the amount of seed required number of trays and assign the tray a number.  All trays are number in this format "A123, A124, A125" etc.

I'm also keen for excel to then assign the seed batch to the order and a tray number to the order.

Firstly is this possible, I've used excel a fair bit from my previous work experience but this is quite new for me and I am keen to learn so if someone could point me in the right direction on a possible method and what I should be looking at!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a data(base) structure for this challenge. Yes, that could be done in Excel, some VBA skills will probably come in handy if you want to achieve it automatically. As a first step, you could e.g. set up something like this:
[Mockup of a data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTbUm.png)

So you would at least need one table where you enter your **orders**, one **list of trays** and one table where you **link** your incoming orders to the trays. You might need more columns than I added in my mockup.

Hope that gets you started